# Re-create distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, key, distribution

I'm fixing an iPhone app as an emergency, but I have a problem, the previous developer didn't leave his Keys so I'm unable to install the distribution certificate.

I couldn't find any other solution to the "valid sinning identity not found" other than import the keys from the original machine that requested the distribution certificate.

So I'm thinking to delete the distribution certificate and create it again, this could be a problem to the other published apps?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320255/if-i-revoke-an-existing-distribution-certificate-will-it-mess-up-anything-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to his provisioning portal account, then yes, you can recreate the developer identity and signing certificates, and reissue the app without a problem.

All of these credentials have expiration dates and do expire regularly without lapse in app availability. I have an app that I last updated in 2010, and have since been through 3 certificate cycles, without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

From here apple https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG6

Important: Members of the Standard iOS Developer Program can be assured that replacing either your developer or distribution certificate will not affect any existing apps that you've published in the iOS App Store, nor will it affect your ability to update those apps.