# How to create IPA file without the p12 file

Tags: ios, iphone

My client has given me an older app to update.
I have done update and now i want to update it on the iTunes.
But i don’t have the `p12` file for certificate. And if i am try to download certificate from the developer account than its does not contain the `KEY` so i can’t sign the code with that.

What should i do ? Do i create new certificate? But than should i able to update same app with new Certificate in iTunes connect.

Does `p12` file is compulsory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to codesign IPA without p12 but as you have the developer account you can create the certificate using the CSR and codesign you application and later share this p12 with your client!

You can revoke it after you have paid for your next year of service. It will then prompt you for a new certificate. You submit your CSR, download the new cert, and remake your provisioning profiles.

Comment: But as i said that app is already on the store. Is it affect if i create new certificate and sign app with new Certificate?

Comment: @Kane Creating a new certificate using CSR will not affect application on App Store. But if you are going to upload the new version then in that case you need to codesign with the older certificate.

Comment: And which i dont have its p12 file right? what happen if i add it with new certificate.

Comment: And yes i want to update the app on store. Does that means i must p12 file?

Comment: You can revoke it after you have paid for your next year of service. It will then prompt you for a new certificate. You submit your CSR, download the new cert, and remake your provisioning profiles.

Comment: @Rachit its not true, you can user your new certificate not the old one for creating the IPA

Comment: See this link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320255/if-i-revoke-an-existing-distribution-certificate-will-it-mess-up-anything-with

Comment: Sorry but little bit confuse here. I dont have p12 or previous Cirtificate or the older CSR. If i create new CSR and use that to create new Distribution Certificate, and use that certificate to sign my new updated app. Than is i am able to update same app on iTunesconnect?

Comment: Yes, there is not problem, see my link

Comment: For better understanding of how profile and certificate works go through [this link](http://escoz.com/blog/demystifying-ios-certificates-and-provisioning-files/).