# How do I replace an iOS certificate in a production environment?

Tags: ios, csr

We currently have a few iOS apps running in production using certificate A. But we lost the public and private keys, so we're going to remake the certificate/app ID/provisioning profile.

Are there any consequences to this? Will out apps in production not work anymore when we remove the certificates?

What would be the best order to tackle this issue? 
I was thinking of remaking everything first, then publish the app in the Apple Store under the new certificate and then remove the old certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revoking distribution certificate will not effect application hosted in App Store. You can create new certificate and for next version you may use this.

Comment: So if the current users have the app that uses certificate B and I'm updating the app with certificate A, this won't affect them in any way? Or if I remove the certificate B from the developer.apple.com platform, this also won't affect them?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2671101?threadID=2671101,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320255/if-i-revoke-an-existing-distribution-certificate-will-it-mess-up-anything-with