# Distribution Enterprise Certificate got revoked.Is there any way to avoid reinstallation of existing apps

Tags: ios

Distribution Enterprise Certificate got revoked.Is there any way to avoid reinstallation of existing apps.
It'll be difficult to ask all users to install app again.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320255/if-i-revoke-an-existing-distribution-certificate-will-it-mess-up-anything-with

Comment: It's an enterprise build.Old apps are getting issue as "Untrusted Enterprise Developer".Is there any way to resolve this without giving another enterprise build.

Answer (score 0):

If your Certificate is revoked, it will be deleted from the list of certificates. No need to reinstall existing apps.

Comment: it is removed from list of certificates.but now the problem is all the users are getting message as "Untrusted Enterprise Developer".Is there any way i can resolve this without giving another enterprise build.

Comment: It was trusted before and was working fine.but recently the certificate was revoked and now its not working.Status is showing "Not Verified" on Users Device Management Settings