# Are apple certificates needed after publishing the app?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store-connect

I'm using React-Native (Expo) to build my Apps. After launching an app, I end up with many certificates (Push Notifications, Distribution, Development, etc) on my developer portal.

**Are these certificates needed on my developer portal after publishing the app or can I revoke/delete them?**

Answer (score 0):

I think no problem if you do that.

- [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/)
- [If I revoke an existing distribution certificate, will it mess up anything with existing apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320255/if-i-revoke-an-existing-distribution-certificate-will-it-mess-up-anything-with)
- [What happens when a distribution certificate expires or revoked?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294421/what-happens-when-a-distribution-certificate-expires-or-revoked)