# What will happen when iOS provisioning profile will be deleted

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have downloaded a provisioning profile (entreprise adhoc) from Apple Developer Portal) on my computer. Now the provisioning profile was deleted from the portal by accident.
I would like to know if I can use the provisioning profile to sign and deploy an app in MobileIron MDM ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I revoke an existing distribution certificate, will it mess up anything with existing apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320255/if-i-revoke-an-existing-distribution-certificate-will-it-mess-up-anything-with)

Comment: There are many answers to this and similar questions on stackoverflow already, as well as in the apple developer forums (see the duplicate mark above, where the answer also answers your question). If you have the profile already, you also could have simply tried it and see did it work

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin My question is about a provisioning profile, the question which you mentioned is about a certificate. Those questions are not the same.

Comment: I actually believe you can still use the provisioning profile to sign an distribute the app, as long as the certificate hasn't expired, the profile hasn't expired, and the app ID matches the app you are building with.  The safest thing to do is to just generate a new provisioning profile, and use it going forward.  It should only take a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Since Xcode 8 most provisioning profiles are managed by Xcode itself meaning that if one expires or one is deleted from the developer portal, then Xcode will simply create a new provisioning profile for you. This means you won't have any problems with building and distributing the app.

If it was deleted and you are not managing the profile through Xcode then you will need to generate a new provisioning profile and install it on your build machine prior to doing a release build.

You may find the following article of use in understanding more about managing provisioning profiles and certificates:

https://medium.com/@euginedubinin/ios-tips-maintaining-your-signing-identities-and-certificates-c04c482ca493