# iOS Distribution Certificates

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, apple-developer-account, ios-app-signing

I would like to know if iOS distribution I can use for various applications, for example I used my iOS distribution in the application to it is already in production now I want to use this same iOS distribution in application b to also put into production is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can publish any number of apps

Comment: Yes, you can create number of apps using one certificate. You need to create separate profile for each aoo

Comment: Did you like any of the answers here? If so then can you please mark the accepted answer. If not explain what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Certificates are just a private and public key pair. You can use single certificate for signing multiple apps. But you need a separate provisioning profile for every app. Every app must have a unique bundle identifier. If you explore developer account and create a new provisioning file you will be able to select your old certificate in it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use one certificate for multiple app but you bundle identifier (i.e com.yourappname.complanyname) should be different for each app

Answer (score -1):

A certificate/driver license/ID card is attached to an author/app publisher<sup>†</sup>

A single author can have thousands of books/apps.

For each book they will dictate who can download it. e.g. only people with these email address can download this books.

Hence every book needs an email list/ provisioning profile.

---

**†:** Each certificate is created by the developer's Macbook. A user doesn't need multiple driver licenses to identify himself, yet he *can* create multiple ID cards for himself. In the real world a user can't have multiple driver licenses of a given state. But in the world of computers, I could create 100s of certificates for myself. Each certificate would have its own expiry date. The certificate will become invalid either by reaching its expiry date or by manual revocation through apple developer portal.

In the image below you can see that the certificate has an expiry date and that I can also revoke the certificate at any time:

[image]

To learn more about revocation and its effect, I highly recommend you to see [If I revoke an existing distribution certificate, will it mess up anything with existing apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320255/if-i-revoke-an-existing-distribution-certificate-will-it-mess-up-anything-with)

Answer (score -3):

No you can not do this. One certificate corresponds to one app. You have to create another certificate for other app