# Visual Studio iOS Hot Restart 'Error iOS code signing key'

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui

I accidently deleted my App Store Connect API Key that was synced to Visual Studio iOS Hot Restart (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/hot-restart?view=net-maui-8.0) used to deploy my NET MAUI app to my Local iOS Device.

I setup a new App Store Connect API Key and went through the setup to add the new App Store Connect API Key in Visual Studio. However, now when trying to build I get the following error:

**Error iOS code signing key 'Apple Development: Created via API (##########)' not found in keychain. FooApp C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\16.4.7132\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets 38**

Where '##########' appears to the old Key ID. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding to no avail. I have no idea where and what is holding onto the old Key ID! Help! Cannot currently run my app at all on my Local iOS Device due to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out how to resolve this issue in a NET MAUI project. The following steps resolved this issue for me:

1. Right click your project on Solution Explorer
2. Select Properties,
3. Expand iOS node
4. Select 'Bundle Signing'
5. Under 'Scheme' caption you'll find a dropdown; make sure it is set to 'Automatic Provisioning'
6. Select 'Configure Automatic Provisioning' and you should see your new Key listed
7. Select Key and this will sync things back up

Hope this helps someone down the road!

Comment: Credit  @MatiasMasso comment in this post for pointing me in the right direction:     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009771/xamarin-ios-code-signing-key-not-found-in-keychain

Comment: Great work! Please consider accepting your answer, which may help others with similar issues! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @LiqunShen-MSFT ! I will accept it as the answer but have to wait 24 hours before SO will allow me.