# iOS Provisioning and Certifcates - Will Revoke/Renew effect App Store Apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, certificate

While working on a new version of one of my apps Xcode told me today, that it cannot run the project any more because the development profile has expired.

The organizer shows for **all** development profiles "Valid signing identity not found" and for **all** distribution profiles "Profile has expired".

Of course it is not a suprise that profiles expire. In the past all I had to do was a click on "Renew" but this does not work any more. After entering user name and password for my Account Xcode shows the error message "No value was provided for the parameter 'certificateIds'"...

What can I do?

Instead of using the Organizer the directly visited the Provisioning Center webpage. There are two entries within the section "iOS Apps/Certificates/All": 
1. "My Name iOS Development Expires: Mar, 17 2012"
2. "My Name Development Expires: Mar, 19 2013"

A click on one of the certificates show option to "Revoke" or "Download" certificate. There is also a "+ Button" to create a new Certificate but the option "iOS App Development Sign development versions of your iOS app." is deactivated.

In the section "Provision Profiles" all development profiles are marked as "Active" and all distribution profile as "Expired". Only "Edit" and "Delete" options are available while a "Renew" option is missing. The "Edit" option shows the profile details and "Generate" button. I would assume that "Generate" creates a new version, but after pressing the button only a progress indicator is shown which comes to no result. After I reload the page the status is unchanged.

So, there are no options to renew the existing certificates and profiles (are there?). Thus I have to create new certificates but - as described - this option is grayed out. I Assume that I have to delete / revoke the existing certificates first. A click on "Revoke" shows a very explicit warning: "**Revoking this certificate will invalidate it and any related services or provisioning profiles that use this certificate may be affected.**"

I am afraid that revoking the certificate might effect my existing app in the App Store - that the app might be removed from sale because the certificate they are based on was deleted.

Of course this is a scenario I would like to avoid. Does anyone know **for sure** what happens when using the Revoke option for an existing certificate. Does this even effect App Store apps?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For App Store apps, you don't need to worry. The signing information on app store binaries is only used for the initial validation to ensure it came from you. Once it has been uploaded the binary will be transformed and resigned with Apple's private key, encrypted with Fairplay, etc.

This means revoking your distribution certification will not affect live apps. You only need to worry if you have an enterprise account.

Comment: Can Apple itself revoke an app on your device?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If any one has the same "problem": I just revoked the certificates and it did not effect my live apps :-) I also found the following hint in the Appel docu: "Members of the Standard iOS Developer Program can be assured that replacing either your developer or distribution certificate will not affect any existing apps that you've published in the iOS App Store, nor will it affect your ability to update those apps. "  (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG6)

Comment: What worry for enter prise account, can you point out me to the place where I can access complete functionality of enterprise account!

Comment: Is that also true for apps published on Crashlytics for example? Or any other beta deployment platforms?

Answer (score 30):

No, revoking certificates does not affect apps already on sale. For that matter it won't even affect apps submitted for review. (We had renew a certificate while an update was in review. No problems at all)

Comment: good info this kind of small details are usually hard to find when needed

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Is this answer valid for enterprise account?

Comment: @abdlkdr no. Only for AppStore apps. For enterprise certificate, revoking it will cause all apps signed with it not to be able to be launched. You will need to redeploy with a new working enterprise certificate to the devices.