# Delete all provisioning profiles and certificates from developer account

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl-certificate, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I want to know If all provisioning profiles and certificates are deleted from developer account then what will be happened? Will the apps affected or not?

Please help me to understand this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will Show code Sign in error when you compile your application. don't worry if you deleted all things you can create again.

Comment: live apps affected or not? @mokujin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944796/ios-provisioning-and-certifcates-will-revoke-renew-effect-app-store-apps check this

Comment: Live apps are not affected

Answer (score 4):

First thing is that you can create,edit or delete provisioning profile (developer,distribution) or certificates that not effected already live app(on app-store). But that effected developer provisioning profile that you are using in to your project for testing.

You can Delete all provisioning profiles and certificates. But you have to create again for testing your app in to device as well as upload new app on app-store from iTunes connect.

Apple provide Very nice and clear documentation please read bellow link for more clear

[Provisioning and Development](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html)

Answer (score 2):

Apps already installed in devices will not be affected.

Answer (score 1):

Live apps installed through Apple store will not be affected but builds that are installed on the device for testing or such may work. Once this happened to me on an enterprise profile but the app seemed to work even after deleting the profile from the account.