# The app couldn't be installed because developer certificate is no longer valid

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

I have invited one TestFlight user from iTunes to test my app. The app is currently under review status. When that user tried to install the app, at the time of launching in iTunes, it throws the following error :

**Could not install XXXX.
The app couldn't be installed because the developer's certificate is no longer valid. To resolve the issue, contact the developer.**

Anyone can provide brief explanation what could be the reason for this and how it can be resolved.

Comment: Try with new Provisinoining profile OR if P12 certificate revoked then create new one & generate new provisioning profile for it

Comment: But what if he wants to download the app that is already uploaded for review through testflight ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It simply means that the developer account from which this app is uploaded is expired **OR** the development/distribution certificates of the app are expired or revoked. It can be resolved by activating the certificates of the app on apple's developer portal.

Comment: Does this break an existing build in iTunes Connect that has been approved, but is pending developer release?

Comment: @vcardillo I don't think it will break an existing build see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944796/ios-provisioning-and-certifcates-will-revoke-renew-effect-app-store-apps

Comment: your answer is not clear enough. what does it mean to activate a certificate?

Answer (score 18):

I encountered this error because the build was signed using a provisioning profile whose certificate had been revoked.

When i checked in the developer center, the provisioning profile was marked as "Invalid".

I just clicked "Edit", selected the new developer certificate and regenerated the provisioning profile. When the new build was uploaded on testflight signed with the new provisioning profile, the error went away.

However, i do think Apple should be checking if the provisioning profile is still valid rather than developers finding it out after build is already approved by TestFlight and testers complain about this error.

Comment: Exactly, thank you. Testflight should include provisioning profile validation checking.

Answer (score 2):

We have uploaded a version to apple-test flight and apple approved app for external testers. Now we're trying to download and is not working, got same message.

But if we run app from dev phone push notification works so P12 still valid. And distributed with old test flight process works.

We're trying to upload another version and see if works.

Comment: We are having the same exact problem did a new upload resolve the problem for you?

Answer (score 2):

I try and try again until I read a comment on the apple forum:

> This XC profile will be acceptable for upload, but is incompatible with Testflight

When you have to check provisioning profile, be sure any "XC" provisioning profile is selected (you can change it by clicking on the right arrow)

[image]

*more details on the "goldstee" answer : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18446*

Answer (score 1):

The error CLearly states what is wrong, your Certificate needs to be renewed, as your certificate may have expired or revoked, Try to create the Certificate again along with the provisioning profiles, and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different issue which was a bit more puzzling as everything was 'valid'. I encountered the issue when I needed a production push certificate (which I already set 2-3 months before and tested!).

This is what I've done to resolve the issue:

1. Check xocde - both Code Signing and Provisioning Profile:
   I had the correct settings (they matched what I was expecting and what I used for a previous build).
2. Check my apple developer account - it stated that my 'prod' profile was 'Active'
3. Check `xcode -> prefrences -> provisioning profiles` - I found the profile I could see in apple developer. It had the same expiry date too!
4. Wet back to my Apple Developer account, clicked on the profile, downloaded it and double clicked on it.

That fixed the problem for me.

If you encounter any issues, I suggest you check Parse [guide](https://parse.com/tutorials/push-notifications) (yes, I know they are shutting down but their doc is very good!). It covers more than just profiles but you can choose the step you are having an issue with.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found everything is fine, both provisioning profile and certificates were valid.

What I did wrong is, I upload the build to TestFligth using Transporter app, which usually needs an .ipa for same but choose adHoc type instead of AppStore while exporting the binary in the organiser.

Which somehow allow the build to upload to TestFlight but didn't authorised to install on the user's device.

So make sure you're choosing the right option while exporting the build.