# creating a new .cer for the app under development at iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Our developer has left us in the middle. He was the one who set up the .cer, .pem & .p12 files. We got the beta build at the iTunes Connect. But do not wish to continue what he has started. ( the private key would have his password piece in it ).

Would it be totally OK to ditch this app at the iTunes Connect ( basically delete it ) and start a brand new .cer generation process?

Is there anything that we need to be aware of in doing so?

Comment: yes, it works. you can revoke the old certificates and make new

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can replace any signing certs/keys/profiles. All what`s required to update an existing app is the source and the same bundle ID.

Check this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944796/ios-provisioning-and-certifcates-will-revoke-renew-effect-app-store-apps) as well.