# Apple certificates from old computer not working

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, certificate

Apple only allows you to create two production certificates. I have created two of those on my old computer, and when I was going to submit a new app from my new computer I discovered that it is not possible to add these certificates to keychain on my new computer (it's a phonegap app).

What are my options here? I'd prefer not to revoke any of the certificates because they are used for active apps.

Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do you still have access to the old computer?

   - If yes, you can export the certificates from the old computer keychain access app , copy them to the new one and add them to keychain
2. Do you wish to use the old computer for publishing apps any more?

   - If not, go ahead and just create a new certificate signing request from your new computer and get a new certificate. [It wont affect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320255/if-i-revoke-an-existing-distribution-certificate-will-it-mess-up-anything-with) [your existing live apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263761/will-revoking-distribution-certificate-affect-application-which-is-in-review-on)

Comment: Right now I don't have access to my old computer, but I do not intend  to use it anymore. If i understand you correctly I can then just revoke a certificate and create a new on on the new computer.

Comment: yes.. thats correct.. if you are skeptical, check the links i have added on the "It wont affect your existing live apps" part