# Can my app be reviewed if my certificate is revoked?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Two weeks ago I submitted my app to the App Store and it got approved (version 1.0.0).

A couple days ago, I submitted an update, which is currently "Waiting For Review" (version 1.0.1).

Last night, however, I accidentally revoked my certificate that was used to sign 1.0.1 (that version is also on TestFlight, and now I am unable to download the TestFlight version 1.0.1 because the certificate was revoked).

**Will this also affect my version 1.0.1 that is "Waiting For Review"? Should I go ahead and submit a new build with a good certificate? This is time sensitive because there's an evil deadline I need to hit.**

---

For reference, I've checked several places and haven't been able to find a clear answer:

- https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/ ("If your iOS Developer Program membership is valid, your existing apps on the App Store will not be affected. However, you will no longer be able to submit new apps or updates to the App Store." ... doesn't mention the specific case of App Store review)
- [Will revoking Distribution certificate affect application which is In Review (on apple store) for Iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263761/will-revoking-distribution-certificate-affect-application-which-is-in-review-on) (latest answer in from 2013, and no sources are cited)
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW34 ("Re-creating your development or distribution certificates doesn’t affect apps that you’ve submitted to the store nor does it affect your ability to update them." ... doesn't mention the specific case of App Store review)

### edit

For reference, here's the message I'm getting in TestFlight:

[image]

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. For reference, several questions like this have been asked in the past (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263761/will-revoking-distribution-certificate-affect-application-which-is-in-review-on) for an example). Also, accoridng to Stackoverflow docs, an appropriate question can be about: "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: @rmaddy, that question does not have an accepted answer, nor does it provide sources :/ I've actually opened a bounty on that specific question in order for someone to provide references.

Comment: It's still a duplicate question and the answer is correct, references or not.

Comment: @rmaddy, right, the answer appears correct :) but it looks anecdotal. Have you had specific experience with this type of issue? Only reason I'm not liking that answer provided in the other question is because there's no evidence other than "according to Apple Support" with no documentation provided. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's a simple fact. The certificate is only used to sign your app to prove to Apple it really came from you. Since it's been submitted (and Apple knows it really came from you), the certificate is irrelevant. Apple will re-sign your app for the store once approved.

Comment: @rmdaddy makes sense :) well, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!