# IOS App go down if certificate is invalid / been revoked

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I accidentally pressed the reset button on 'IOS Distribution' within IOS Developer account. This in turn made a hand-full of provisioning profiles invalid.

From what I have read here: https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/ 
apps are still intact I will no longer be able to submit new apps or updates to the App Store.

Just want to verify if this is correct in my case and apps will not go down??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , the current apps will have no effect of the certificate being revoked.
Happened with me many times .

similar question threads here

[Will revoking Distribution certificate affect application which is In Review (on apple store) for Iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263761/will-revoking-distribution-certificate-affect-application-which-is-in-review-on)

[If I revoke an existing distribution certificate, will it mess up anything with existing apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320255/if-i-revoke-an-existing-distribution-certificate-will-it-mess-up-anything-with)

Answer (score 2):

If you are revoked .cer then you can generate it again and that does not effect on your live application.

In the developer Member Center there is your generated  application ID that you generate for each application. You must take care about that Application id is not removed else you need to generate it as a new because its a unique and in this case you need add new app app and you can not update the current application that live.

**What kind of steps you need to do if .CER revoked or expire:**

- If .cer revoked then just click on add new and select your [CSR(Certificate Signing Request)](https://www.codementor.io/ios/tutorial/apple-developer-distribution-certificate)
- Now you have new cer then you need to just update your provisional profile and download it and use it thats it